# Java classes written outside of class brackets

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I'm confused as to what this is called in Java and what this does:

```
    public class MainFrame(){
        public static void main(String[] args{
            //etc.
        }    
    }//end class
    class SampleMenuListener implements MenuListener(){

    }//end SampleMenuListener
```

I researched inner classes and know how to use anonymous inner classes however I know this is not one and after some googling I couldn't figure out what this is called in Java.  So my questions are what is this called?  And in Eclipse the Class C shows up next to class SampleMenuListener.  So is this essentially the same thing as making a new class in the same project folder called SampleMenuListener and making an instance of it in MainFrame?  And if so is this simply just a shorthand way of writing another class without making it separate in eclipse?  Or does it some how differ and how does it differ?  Definitely feel free to post links as this may be a stupid question but like I said I couldn't seem to google the right keywords to get results on what this is called in Java.

Comment: If a `class` need not be `public`, it can be written in the file where it is being used. Irrespective of Eclipse or any IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, we like to say that Java can only have one class per code file, and that the source file must be named for the class.  This isn't entirely true.  The actual **rule is that you can only have one *public* class per code file**.  You can have as many as you want *(but please don't...)*, so long as no more than one of them is `public`.

The others must be package access (no access specifier).  See [the relevant documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html)

In your example `SampleMenuListener` is simply a `class` like any other.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal  class , it is just written in same .java file.
only difference is there is only one public  class allowed(as file name need to be same as of public class )

Comment: Not really a super class. The other class does not extend it.

Comment: I have updated my answer, i was telling super in the context of normal class that can be used as super any where based on visiblity